# Is it possible to make an app like paytm using PhoneGap?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

Are there any limits to making apps use phonegap? I need to make an app in which lot of database processes take place. Is it possible to make an app like that using PhoneGap?

Comment: Phonegap is something you can write your frontend with. You will need an API that the phonegap interface can connect to. The API will talk to the DB. So in that case there are no limitations since they are separate tools for an applications infrastructure.

Comment: Can you give a right tutorial ?

Comment: I think that searching for a tutorial is the most basic part of research that you should perform by yourself.

Comment: I agree with @DragomirKolev.. the pattern he proposes is correct. Search for restful API, for example. But remember to implement a login to protect the connection, otherwise everyone can talk with your APIs